# Rename "Heretic" tag to "Heresy"

Tags: discussion, tags

I just asked a question titled ["What is the difference between a Heretic and a Schismatic"](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/26733/what-is-the-difference-between-a-heretic-and-a-schismatic-according-catholic-an) , and when I was selecting the tags, I noticed that I could use the tags "Heretic" and "Schism".

I believe `heresy` is a better tag than `heretic`, as the former suggests a group of people while the latter suggests a single person.

"Schism" likewise suggests the belief of a group of people, whereas "schismatic" suggests the belief of one person.

Comment: I think it's ok to have synonym tags

Comment: @AaronKorn why not just dump them into one tag, given they indicate the same thing?

Answer (score 6):

Actually both tags already existed so I'm not sure why you chose to tag your question with the variant you say here (and I agree) is not as optimal. I have retagged your question and the other two on the site that used [heretic](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heretic) with [heresy](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heresy). I also merged the plural version into the main one. As long as no questions pop up using the wrong tags in a couple days the now empty tags will be removed automatically.

I don't really see the need for synonyms at this point as only a few oddball questions had the variant tags. If this proves to be an ongoing point of confusion after the existing tags no longer auto-complete then we can certainly make synonyms.

Comment: Oops I must have not seen the other options. Thanks!